# Can't bind to 'routerlink' since it isn't a known property of 'a' when doing the tutorial

Tags: angular

I'm following the introduction on angular tutorial to create Tour of Heroes app. However, when doing the search Heros function, I get error: Can't bind to 'routerlink' since it isn't a known property of 'a'. Can anyone help me with the problem?
My code: https://github.com/kiddomagic/TourOfHeroes
*Note: I have looked for the same questions but none of this solve my problem.

Comment: I had a quick glimpse and it seems that you don't have the square brackets around `routeLink`.

Comment: ok, let me try that

Comment: You know, after I added it and check all the attribute to see if there is something wrong, it work!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RouterModule adds router directives and providers, it needs to be imported in module where routing is required, if required globally import RouterModule to root module of angular app.

I went through your code, you can also use another syntax for defining routing in html(view).

For example:

```
<a [routerLink]="['/detail/{{hero.id}}']">Hero Details</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the RouterModule to imports of all modules where routerLink or router-outlet is being used